# Identify whether to have unique output in this ARMA system

Tags: discrete-signals

my friends and I have no idea whether to diagnose to have the specific output from  the formula below:
[image]

The question is that Assume we are given a specific input signal x[k]x[k]. Explain and justify whether or not there is a unique output y[k] satisfying this difference equation.

Would somebody please answer this question asap??

Thank you

Comment: I don't see $x[k]$ (for any value of $k$) in the equation. This means that the signal $y$ is not created by a signal put into a filter. There may be a signal that satisfies that equation, but it does not depend on any input signal. I suspect that there is a typographical error. I suspect that one of the sums on the right-hand side should involve $x[k-i]$ or $x[k-j]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I think there is a typographical error in the equation. I think it is supposed to be
\begin{equation}
y[k] = \sum_{i=1}^{M}a_iy[k-i] + \sum_{j=1}^{N}b_jx[k-j].
\end{equation}
This is an example of a linear constant-coefficient [difference equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation). These are introduced very early in most textbooks about digital signal processing. For example, they are introduced in Section 2.5 (page 33) in the 1989 edition of *Discrete-Time Signal Processing* by [Oppenheim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_V._Oppenheim) and [Schafer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_W._Schafer).

Given an input signal $x$, there will *not* be a unique solution signal $y$. This is because a specific solution requires specifying the input signal as well as *initial conditions* for $y$. Different initial conditions lead to different solutions.

You may gain some insight into the subject from Oppenheim himself in [lecture 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XT6o4IRTcLk&list=PL8157CA8884571BA2) of a [DSP course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8157CA8884571BA2) recorded in 1975 and now posted online.